# Filter items in Redux state with searchbox

Tags: search, redux

I have a list of objects in my redux state. I am trying to filter them using a searchbox and dispatching an action on every change. My state does update when I type but doesn't go back (doesn't show all contents) when I delete. I believe that I'm modifying the state and so when search bar is empty again, there is nothing left to filter.

header.js

```
export const Header = () =>{
const locationsDropdown = useSelector(selectAllLocations);
const departmentsDropdown = useSelector(selectAllDepartments);
const employees = useSelector(selectAllEmployees)

const dispatch = useDispatch()
const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("")

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchField(e.target.value)
    dispatch(listFiltered(searchField))
    console.log(employees)
}
```

snippet from employeeSlice.js (reducer action)

```
     listFiltered:{
        reducer(state, action) {
            //filters the array but when search is deleted, items don't come back
            return state.filter(item => item.fname.includes(action.payload)) 
        }
    }
```

If I try to use this function in header.js (where search field is located), everything works well.

```
    const filtered = employees.filter(item => {
        const itemName = item.fname
        return itemName.includes(searchField)
     })
```

Problem is that header.js component is not responsible for rendering items where needed and I don't how (if possible) to export 'filtered' result to other components

Comment: Can you store the `searchField` in redux rather than filtering the items? Then, you can use both the items and the `searchField` wherever you need to display the filtered results.